# what is the meaning of the icons beside the project in Solution Explorer Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

What does the circled Icon mean? It looks like a beaker to me?

[image: My solution]

Comment: The icon represents a Unit Test project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "beaker" Icon represents a project which has been created with the ***Unit Test Project*** [Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0fyc0azh%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) in Visual Studio:

[image: Unit Test Project]

I am not certain about your Visual Studio version but it should be at least 2012. Having said that the icon could differ in different VS versions.

More about: [Unit Tests in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598960.aspx)

P.S: If the solution you posted is under your control consider renaming the project to something useful, e.g. BusinessDataGlobals**Test**.

Comment: actually it is not a unit test project, don't suppose you know how to tell VS that?

Comment: You can unload the project and then edit the project file. Delete evey Unit Test related tag in the `<PropertyGroup>` like `<IsCodedUITest>` and `<TestProjectType>`. But cleaner way would be to create a new project from scratch and add the existing code files to the new project.